# Populate HTML Table with Certain Items from a JSON Array

Tags: javascript, html, json, twitter-bootstrap, axios

I have a JSON array like the following:

```
[
{
    "_id": "5c3296f4c7728833bf7cf334",
    "title": "Update styling",
    "content": "Don't forget to update the styling on the website",
    "category": "Cat2",
    "createdAt": "2019-01-07T00:01:56.375Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-01-07T00:01:56.375Z",
    "__v": 0
}
]
```

I want to populate a html table with the Title, Content and Category fields. Currently, I am using the following code to populate the table, but it puts every field in the table, not the ones I want.

```js
const data = [{ "_id": "5c3296f4c7728833bf7cf334", "title": "Update styling", "content": "Don't forget to update the styling on the website", "category": "Cat2", "createdAt": "2019-01-07T00:01:56.375Z", "updatedAt": "2019-01-07T00:01:56.375Z", "__v": 0 }]
const axios = { get: (s) => Promise.resolve({ data }) };

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  axios.get('http://localhost:2672/categories').then(function (myCategories) {
      // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
      var col = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < myCategories.data.length; i++) {
          for (var key in myCategories.data[i]) {
              if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                  col.push(key);
              }
          }
      }

      // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
      var table = document.createElement("table");

      // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

      var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.

      for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
          var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
          th.innerHTML = col[i];
          tr.appendChild(th);
      }

      // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
      for (var i = 0; i < myCategories.data.length; i++) {

          tr = table.insertRow(-1);

          for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
              var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
              tabCell.innerHTML = myCategories.data[i][col[j]];
          }
      }

      // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
      var divContainer = document.getElementById("showCategories");
      divContainer.innerHTML = "";
      divContainer.appendChild(table);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="showCategories"></div>
```

Any ideas how I would accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your array to only contain the columns you wish to insert into the table. You could filter afterwards with something like:

```
col = col.filter((data) => {
    return data === 'title' || data === 'content' || data == 'category';
});
```

or you could filter within your for-loop with a simple if-statement like so:

```
var col = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myCategories.data.length; i++) {
    for (var key in myCategories.data[i]) {
        if (col.indexOf(key) === -1 && (key === 'title' || key === 'content' || key == 'category')) {
            col.push(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome Ben, that worked perfectly! Is there any way that I can change the name of the headers on the table to make them look prettier, instead of the lowercase title, content and category?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) .

```js
const data = [{"_id":"5c3296f4c7728833bf7cf334","title":"Update styling","content":"Don't forget to update the styling on the website","category":"Cat2","createdAt":"2019-01-07T00:01:56.375Z","updatedAt":"2019-01-07T00:01:56.375Z","__v":0}]

const res = data.map(({title, content, category})=>{
   return `<tr>
      <td>${title}</td>
      <td>${content}</td>
      <td>${category}</td>
   </tr>`;
}).join("");

const table = document.createElement("table");
table.innerHTML = "<tr><th>title</th><th>content</th><th>category</th></tr>";
table.innerHTML += res;
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
table,tr,th,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
}

td,th {
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const axios = { get: (s) => Promise.resolve({ data: [{ "_id": "5c3296f4c7728833bf7cf334", "title": "Update styling", "content": "Don't forget to update the styling on the website", "category": "Cat2", "createdAt": "2019-01-07T00:01:56.375Z", "updatedAt": "2019-01-07T00:01:56.375Z", "__v": 0 }] }) };

function getSelectColumns() {
  const selected = document.querySelectorAll('#headers option:checked');
  return Array.from(selected).reduce((all, el) => {
    return { ...all, [el.value]: el.text }
  }, {});
}

// ------------------------------------------

function createTable(data, columns = {
  title: 'Title', content: 'Content', category: 'Category'
}) {
  const headerCells = Object.values(columns).map(val => `<th>${val}</th>`);
  const headerRow = `<tr>${headerCells.join('')}</tr>`;
  const dataRows = data.map(obj => {
    return Object.keys(columns).map(key => {
      return `<td>${obj[key] || '-'}</td>`;
    }).join('');
  });
  
  return `<table>${headerRow + dataRows.join('')}</table>`;
}

   function loadDataAndTable() {
  return axios.get('http://localhost:2672/categories').then(res => {
    const div = document.getElementById("showCategories");
    div.innerHTML = createTable(res.data, getSelectColumns());
  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => loadDataAndTable());
```

```css
table {
  text-align: left;
}

th, td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

th {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="showCategories"></div>
<hr>
<p>Hold shift and select the columns you want in the table.</p>
<select id="headers" multiple onchange="loadDataAndTable()">
  <option value="title" checked>Title</option>
  <option value="content" checked>Content</option>
  <option value="category" checked>Category</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Callam, my only problem is that I am using webpack, and I keep getting `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Frink I think it was the async/await syntax, try thenning the promise instead